# Adding textbox field throws “IndexOutBoundsException” when using Aspose PDF .Net

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.pdf

I’m using Aspose PDF in .Net for creating PDFs.
I have added textbox fields in my code. Before adding the fields my code was working fine and pdf was being created successfully. Since i have added code for textbox fields my code throws the above mentioned exception when saving the file.

During testing it generated the textfield once but after it has failed numerous times.
Following is the code that i have used for creating textfield in a table

```
public static void CreateTextboxTable(Document doc, Page page)
    {
        Table table = new Table();
        table.ColumnWidths = "250 250";
        table.Border = new BorderInfo(BorderSide.All, .5f, Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.Black));
        // Set the border for table cells
        table.DefaultCellBorder = new BorderInfo(BorderSide.All, .5f, Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.Black));
        table.Margin.Top = 5;
        table.DefaultCellPadding = new MarginInfo(3, 3, 3, 3);
        page.Paragraphs.Add(table);

        Row row1 = table.Rows.Add();
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell = row1.Cells.Add("Full Name:");

        Cell fieldCell = row1.Cells.Add();
        // Create a field
        TextBoxField textBoxField = new TextBoxField(doc);
        textBoxField.PartialName = "textbox1";
        textBoxField.Value = "";
        textBoxField.Width = 150;
        textBoxField.Height = 20;
        //textBoxField.Margin.Top = 20;
        Border border = new Border(textBoxField);
        border.Width = 1;
        textBoxField.Border = border;
        textBoxField.Color = Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        // Add field to the document
        doc.Form.Add(textBoxField, 1);
        fieldCell.Paragraphs.Add(textBoxField);
    }
```

Exception occurs when this line is executed:

> pdfDoc.Save(location);

If i remove this call to this function then pdf is produced. also the stack trace is as follows:

```
at Aspose.Pdf.Forms.Field.5kzkyaw9ehlf8lze3k4btj845lj3sczy    (    )
at Aspose.Pdf.Forms.TextBoxField.5kzkyaw9ehlf8lze3k4btj845lj3sczy    (    )
at Aspose.Pdf.Forms.Field.hulrgtdcn4a36jvghassc3d9p8uvbscd    (    , Rectangle )
at ​  .(Field )
at ​  .()
at Aspose.Pdf.Cell.(Table , Double , Page , Double , Double , Boolean )
at Aspose.Pdf.Row.(Table , Page , Double , Double , Int32 )
at Aspose.Pdf.Row.(Table , Double& , Double& , Boolean , Double , Double , Page , Int32&  )
at Aspose.Pdf.Table.(Double& , Double& , Boolean , Double , Double , Page , Boolean , List`1  )
at ​  .()
at Aspose.Pdf.Page.(Page )
at Aspose.Pdf.Document.ProcessParagraphs()
at Aspose.Pdf.Document.(Stream , SaveOptions )
at Aspose.Pdf.Document.(String )
at Aspose.Pdf.Document.Save(String outputFileName)
at AsposePdfApp.Common.Helper.CreatePdf() in \Common\Helper.cs:line 42
```

This stacktrace gives hint problem is with textbox field.

Kindly guide me where is the problem in this code. Thanks

Comment: On what line is the exception being thrown?

Comment: @Crowcoder plz see the edits.

Comment: I doubt the problem is actually with the code you have shown.

Comment: Can you tell me where can be the problem?

Comment: @Harry.Naeem Post the code for `pdfDoc.Save(location);`

Comment: I'm sorry, no, not without the relevant code. Since this doesn't happen until you save the document it may be difficult to locate the problem.

Comment: @VigneshKumarA this is just a statement in my main function. pdfDoc is the document that i created for this whole process and location is a string where i want to save the pdf to

Comment: @Crowcoder as i mentioned that during testing it also created pdf successfully but after some changes it didn't.

Comment: @Harry.Naeem, We have tested the scenario with Aspose.PDF for .NET 18.12 and noticed that API threw exception upon setting TextBoxField value to empty. We have already logged an issue as PDFNET-38686 in our issue tracking system for the sake of correction. We will surely let you know once the issue is fixed. However, as a workaround, you may please set TextBoxField.Value equal to space i.e. " " in order to prevent the issue. I am Asad Ali and I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @AsadAli can you please tell me how to save data in pdf file? I have textfields and i want to save to type data in it and save it?

Comment: @Harry.Naeem Please use next code to fill TextBoxField: 
Aspose.Pdf.Document pdfDocument = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(dataDir + "AddTextBox.pdf");
TextBoxField tbf = (TextBoxField)pdfDocument.Form[1];
tbf.Value = "Aspose";
pdfDocument.Save(dataDir + "FilledPDF.pdf");